# Not detecting graphics card in ubuntu16

Tags: graphics

I am inexperienced.  Have used Ubuntu 16 for > 1 yr without problem. Now, get, on startup "Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly, etc."  Sometimes I get "The program is running in low-graphics mode."  I can then go ahead, ignore further problem warnings, and use the computer without obvious problem, occasionally have to reboot first.  But do I have a major central problem which must be fixed? I have an Intel Graphics Card.